# Django Channels group_send not sending across the opponent_offline in some cases when one user disconnects

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm developing a chess game on Django using Django Channels. Here are the relevant portions of the GameConsumer

```
class GameConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.disconn()
        await self.opp_offline()

    async def opp_offline(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            str(self.game_id),
            {
                "type": "offline.opp",
                'sender_channel_name': self.channel_name
            }
        )
    
    async def offline_opp(self,event):
        if self.channel_name != event['sender_channel_name']:
            await self.send_json({
                "command":"opponent-offline",
            })
            print("sending offline")

    @database_sync_to_async
    def disconn(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]
        game = Game.objects.all().filter(id=self.game_id)[0]
        if game.opponent == user:
            game.opponent_online = False
            print("Setting opponent offline")
        elif game.owner == user:
            game.owner_online = False
            print("Setting owner offline")
        game.save()
```

So what happens is that I want to notify the other online user (if any) that their opponent has disconnected. So here's the case in which there's a problem:

1. The first user connects. It shows that his opponent has not connected yet and tells him to wait.
2. The second user connects. The game starts for both of them.
3. Now the first user disconnects before any moves have been made. The second user does not get the user offline notification. But if it was the other way round ie the second user is the one disconnecting, then the first user gets the notification.
4. But if a move has been made then everything works normally.

Trying to find out where the problem occurs.

You can view the full consumer code [here](https://github.com/kevinjoseph61/chess/blob/master/game/consumers.py)

Comment: Can you add the `connect` method of your consumer?

Comment: I've added the link for the whole consumer in the end. I didn't think it would be relevant

Comment: The whole project is there on [github](https://github.com/kevinjoseph61/chess) in case any of you want more clarification.